# Excluding nested transitive dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

My project depends on `jparsec`, which depends on `cglib`, which depends on `asm`. My project also directly depends on `asm`, but a newer version than the one `cglib` depends on:

[image]

It seems I cannot exclude `asm` from my `jparsec` dependency. When I attempt to exclude it with Eclipse, it makes no change to my pom. If I manually exlude it, it has no effect.

Is my only option here to exclude `cglib` from `jparsec` and then to manually add a dependency on `cglib` with `asm` excluded? This seems a bit convoluted to me, but it does work.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid option to solve this issue. Another option is to place your `asm` dependency above the `jparsec` dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks. Putting `asm` before `jparsec` allowed the exclusion to work against `asm` rather than only against `cglib`. I'm not sure it's technically needed anymore (it built without the exlusion), but I've added it anyway to be explicit. If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, you have 2 options to solve this issue:

1. The one that you suggested, e.g. exclude `cglib` from `jparsec` and add `cglib` with `asm` excluded.
2. Locate your `asm` dependency above the `jparsec` dependency.

Answer (score 5):

I would have expected that if you put `asm` before `jparsec` in your POM, no exclusion would be required. The Maven ["nearest definition"](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) behaviour would kick in to ensure only `4.1` is used.